# iOS: best way to generate unique consecutive numbers with existing numbers removable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unique

I need to generate unique numbers and I can think of the consecutive way, for example, I can have a counter starting from 0, every time a unique number is needed I return the counter and increase the counter by 1, this simply works until I may have a lot of unique numbers which go beyond the range of the data type(say int), also, the generated unique numbers, for example, the counter is 10 but 4 and 5 are not used any more so they can be re-used, how do I make use of the reusable numbers without keeping all of the in a data structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to substitute numbers you've already handed out? If so then as soon as any number is returned, substitute the most recently handed out one with it and decrement the allocation counter. If it's the most recent one that's been returned then skip the substitution.

Otherwise, I guess the best you're going to be able to do is keep a sorted array of ranges.

To allocate a new number:

If the array is empty, create a new range and return the only number in it.

Otherwise, get the first range in the array and increase its length by 1. Return that number. Check whether that makes the first two ranges join up. If so then merge them into a single range.

To return a number:

Find the range it falls within (eg, by binary search; see `NSOrderedSet` if your deployment plans allow it). If the returned number is at either end of the range then just shrink the range. Otherwise split the one into two with the returned number as the hole.